# How to run an import method on a separate thread in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have an import method running however it completely slows down the app and I would like to try and run it on a separate thread to the UI however I'm unsure how to do it. The method needs no parameters passed to it just needs to run separately from the UI.

Comment: look up `AsyncTask` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Are you trying to update the UI from within this method?

Comment: At most I'll need to use Toast to inform the user that the import is done but no UI changes as such

Comment: have a look at this [tutorial](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html) it contains everything you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to create and start a thread which will not block the GUI.

```
Thread thread;
    ImportRunnable importRun;
public void startImport(){
            importRun = new ImportRunnable();
    thread = new Thread(importRun);
    thread.start();
}
    public void stopThread(){
         importRun.setActive(false);
         thread.join();
    }
public class ImportRunnable implements Runnable{
            boolean active;
            public ImportRunnable(){this.active=true;}
    public void run(){
        doImport();
    }
    public void setActive(boolean active){this.active=active;}
    void doImport(){
                while(active){
                    //do import stuff
                }
            }
}
```

This allows you to start and stop a runnable process safely and easily.

Answer (score 2):

Read the all-time favorite blog post about [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2009/05/painless-threading.html) from the **Android Developer Blog**.